# Не работает настройка гема Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Цель - регистрировать пользователя по имени, эл. почте и паролю, а вход выполнять вводя имя и пароль (без указания эл. почты).

Установил гем Devise, добавил модель User:
rails g devise User

К модели User добавил имя :name (rails generate migration AddNameToUser name:string). миграция отработала успешно. Добавляю strong parametres в ApplicationController исходя из моей задачи:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      protect_from_forgery with: :exception

      # настройка для работы девайза при правке профиля юзера
      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters

        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:name, :password])

        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, 
    keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])

      end  

    end
```

Соответственно форма входа для пользователя будет иметь только поля :name и :password (далее сама вьюха):

```
    <h2>Войти</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name, 'имя' %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password, 'твой пароль' %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me, 'хочу чтобы помнили' %>
        </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Вход" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Регистрация нового пользователя отрабатывает нормально. А при входе пользователя по имени и паролю devise выдает "неверный email или пароль". Если во вьюхе поле :name заменить на поле :email - то вход выполняется.

Как перенастроить гем на выполнение входа только по имени и паролю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise по умолчанию использует email в качестве логина. Чтобы изменить это поведение, его нужно [донастроить](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Видимо, нужно сделать одно из двух:

Либо в `config/initializers/devise.rb` добавить строку вида

```
config.authentication_keys = [:name]
```

Либо в модели привести вызов метода `device` к виду

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :authentication_keys => [:name]
# т.е. добавить :authentication_keys => [:name]
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо за ответ и ссылку.